# How to plot the given functions $g$ and $h$ with the assumption $f=0$?

Tags: plotting, numerics, assumptions, conditional, multivalued

I have a constraint `f[a_, b_, c_] ==0` with three parameters $0<a,b,c<3$ where

```
f[a_, b_, c_] = b^6 + 16 b^5 c + 4 (25 - 2 a) b^4 c^2 + 16/3 b^2 (84 + 3 (-26 + a) a - 8 c) c^4 -  16/3 b^3 c^3 (-57 + 18 a + c) +  64/3 b c^5 (12 + 6 (-6 + a) a + (-6 + a) c) + (64/9) ( c^6) (36 (-2 + a) a + 12 (-2 + a) c + c^2)     ;
```

On the other hand, I have two functions `g[b_, c_]` and `h[x_, a_, b_, c_]` with $0<x<10$ as follows

```
g[b_, c_] = -(c^2/(9 (b + 4 c)^2)) ;

h[x_, a_, b_, c_] =  Exp[ -c/x - x Sqrt[c^2/(9 (b + 4 c)^2)] ] (x)^(1 + b/( 2 c)) (1 + (2 a)/c x);
```

**My question.**

> I want to plot the two functions `g[b_, c_]` and `h[x_, a_, b_, c_]` with the assumption that the condition `f[a_, b_, c_] ==0` holds, I mean plotting $g$ and $h$ only for those $a,b,c$ which satisfy `f[a_, b_, c_] ==0`.

I appreciate any help and comments in advance.

**P.S.** I know that something like `RegionFunction` works for inequality conditions but do not know how to impose the condition with equality sign.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the conditions it gives are quite complicated.

Comment: @Bill If I knew how to deal with the problem (or equivalently if I was an expert in Mathematica as you are) I would not post my question here!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here a workaround using `RegionFunction` in a small stripe

```
eps = .001
ContourPlot3D[g[b, c], {a, 0, 3}, {b, 0, 3}, {c, 0, 3}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b, c}, -eps < f[a, b, c] < eps]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So, in general, there is no way to impose an equality condition explicitly on a plot?

Comment: Usually as far as I know `ContourPlot3D` is only able to detect surfaces